# something like <activity-alias> for services in android

Tags: android, android-service

**TLDR**:

I need something like [activity-alias](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element) for services in android.

**Full version**:

I am storing [component names](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName) (fully qualified names) of some services in my db. Now, I need to change the physical locations of these service components from one place to other which means their fully qualified path will change and in this case, their package will also change. That means that when I get them from the db next time, I won't be able to invoke them.

While in case of activities, we can just create an activity-alias in manifest at the old location, I didn't see anything like that for services.

One obvious solution is to update the db at boot time, but I was wondering if there are any more elegant solutions available.

Edit: I'll be moving these services across multiple releases, so it won't be single time migration and I can't maintain a single key as the status of migration.

Comment: If your `minSdkVersion` is 28 or higher, you could use [`AppComponentFactory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppComponentFactory) to intercept references to the old component name and instantiate the new class. However, it is only 2020, so I will be stunned if your `minSdkVersion` is `28` or higher.

Comment: This class serves the purpose ! but yes, minsdk is not 28 :) . Is there something similar for lower versions?

Comment: No, sorry, there is no real equivalent for older Android versions.